# how to create a new map when i developped the free ,copy and compare functions

Tags: c, dictionary, struct

hi i developped some functions to create a map of type tournament but i dont know how to create this map;
i'm confused with the struct map_t that we define in the map.c module and my map that i want to create in the tournment.c module

```
    struct node
{
    MapDataElement data;
    MapKeyElement key;
    struct node* next;
};

struct Map_t
{
    Node Head; //first node of the linked list that point of the next
    copyMapDataElements copyDataElement;
    copyMapKeyElements copyKeyElement;
    freeMapDataElements freeDataElement;
    freeMapKeyElements freeKeyElement;
    compareMapKeyElements compareKeyElements;
    Node iterator;  //iterator that is here for the user can move into the linked list
};
```

and here is my tournament data type that i'm defining in tournament.c

```
struct tournament_data
{
    char* tournament_location;
    Winner result;
    Game Head_Game;
    Game game_iterator;
    Player_stats Head_Player;
    Player_stats player_iterator
};

struct Tournament_node
{
    int id_tournament;
    Tournament_data data;
    tournament* next;
};
```

here some functions from the chess systeme.c

```
void* copyKeyTournament(void* tournament)
{
    return (void *) copyTournamentKey(tournament);
}

void* copyDataTour(void* tournament)
{
    return copyTournamentData(tournament);
}

void freeKeyTour(void* tournament)
{
    freeTournamentKey(tournament);
}

void freeDataTour(void* tournament)
{
    freeDataTournament(tournament);
}
int compareTournament(void* tournament1,void* tournament2)
{
    return compareTwoTournaments(tournament1,tournament2);
}

struct chess_system_t{
    Tournament Head;
    copyMapDataElements ;
    copyMapKeyElements ;
    freeMapKeyElements ;
    freeMapDataElements ;
    compareMapKeyElements ;
    Tournament iterator;
};
```

i m tring to do that but i con't fill the copyMapDataElement with my copyDataTour function

here the typedef of copymapdata and copymapKey

```
/** Type of function for copying a data element of the map */
typedef MapDataElement(*copyMapDataElements)(MapDataElement);

/** Type of function for copying a key element of the map */
typedef MapKeyElement(*copyMapKeyElements)(MapKeyElement);
```

Comment: For clarity you must remove "pointer" from typedefs, so it reads `node *next;` and not `node next;` It is often a source of errors and confusion.

Comment: In `struct Map_t` it reads `copyMapDataElements copyDataElement;` - Could you please provide their typedefs? They seem function.

Comment: yes they are function

Comment: `chess_system_t` seems to have unfinished definitions like `copyMapDataElements ;`

Comment: Please turn warnings of your compiler on and fix any warnings. For example `node` is undefined (`struct node` is, but that is something else).

Comment: i don t know what to write in this field because there is an error if im filling with copyDataTour or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you want to do but it is a bit over-ambitious and difficult to help you in detail, so I will give the outline of a simplified approach:

The simplified idea is that your `map.c` functions know everything about `map` but nothing about data`. And they shouldn't need to; it is the task of the specific data functionality to provide all the data manipulation functions.

So the general form of a map is:

```
typedef struct map_node
{
    void *map_data;           // MapDataElement
    void *map_key;            // MapKeyElement
    struct map_node *next;
}
map_node;
```

This map knows nothing about the data or key. This type is only known to the map module; it is not exported.

Your map provides a structure in which the user can place manipulation functions. I removed that concept. instead, the map module exports functions like:

```
void *create_map(void *data, void *key);
```

Everything is void, unnamed pointers: the function returns an unnamed object for the user to use, and receives two unnamed objects to store in the map.

```
void *get_map_element( void *map, void *data);
```

Here `map` is the thing earlier returned by `create_map`, a `map_node` as defined earlier.

OK; I hope this gives you the idea.